# Get aks publicIP/loadbalancer IP of Kuberbenetes address after apply bedrock terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, ip-address, azure-aks

Currently I'm applying following terraform template in order to create kubernetes cluster, everything work as I expected.

```
module "subnet" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/microsoft/bedrock//cluster/azure/subnet/?ref=master"

  subnet_name          = var.subnet_name
  vnet_name            = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.keyvault.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefix]
}

module "aks-gitops" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/microsoft/bedrock//cluster/azure/aks-gitops/?ref=master"

  acr_enabled              = var.acr_enabled
  agent_vm_count           = var.agent_vm_count
  agent_vm_size            = var.agent_vm_size
  cluster_name             = var.cluster_name
  dns_prefix               = var.dns_prefix
  flux_recreate            = var.flux_recreate
  gc_enabled               = var.gc_enabled
  gitops_ssh_url           = var.gitops_ssh_url
  gitops_ssh_key_path      = var.gitops_ssh_key_path
  gitops_path              = var.gitops_path
  gitops_poll_interval     = var.gitops_poll_interval
  gitops_label             = var.gitops_label
  gitops_url_branch        = var.gitops_url_branch
  kubernetes_version       = var.kubernetes_version
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.cluster_rg.name
  service_principal_id     = var.service_principal_id
  service_principal_secret = var.service_principal_secret
  ssh_public_key           = var.ssh_public_key
  vnet_subnet_id           = module.subnet.subnet_id
  network_plugin           = var.network_plugin
  network_policy           = var.network_policy
  oms_agent_enabled        = var.oms_agent_enabled
}
```

The next step in terrafrom is configure the CDN/Domain setup, and it requires the public IP address (which already created in above steps under module "aks-gitops") but the output seem to be not returned with that Ip address.

Any idea for that, since I've just dug all the resource on internet.

every comment is appreciated. !

Thank mates !

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the FQDN which resolves to the public IP of the cluster, create a `data` resource that references the newly created cluster.

```
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-cluster" {
  name                = var.cluster_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.cluster_rg.name
}
```

The address of the newly created cluster can then be accessed via `data.aks-cluster.fqdn`

You can follow a similar pattern to retrieve details of a load balancer, or any other resource that is not returned in the module outputs.

Comment: I've got the error when applied your above suggestion:

```
Error: Error: Managed Kubernetes Cluster "mt-emea-prod01" was not found in Resource Group "mt-emea-prod01"

```

It means that terraform got the problem when it tried to retrieve the existing kubernetes, not for newly created.

Comment: It sounds like the data source is looking for the cluster before it is created. Try using the last segment of `module.aks-gitops.aks_resource_id` instead of the name variable so the dependency tree is created (e.g. `element(reverse(split('/', module.aks-gitops.aks_resource_id)),0)`). Let me know if that works and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I created your suggested data source and add depends_on at the last and above error disappears, but it seem that the data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks-cluster does not contains the ip/ipv4 of newly created cluster.

Your suggestion is fqdn which is the url, not much help in my case, but I am really appreciate your suggestion about data source.

Comment: @HaiTran - The IP address is not provided as an output of the AKS terraform provider (ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#attributes-reference). "Domain/CDN setup" is potentially achievable using a CNAME record pointing to the FQDN. Please note that using `depends_on` in a data source is not recommended in terraform.